# send values of dynamic table to a flask app

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

sorry for this begginer question iam compeltly noob in JQuery i have a flask form thats contain a dynamic table i want to send values of the table to my backend its nearly done but i get values of secound td for etc if i enter the pizza in first td and enter 20 in secound td i get this in my back-end : { "" : "20"}
this is my html ( i cut most the flask form from my cod):

```
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1>New Cafe</h1>
                        <p class="text-muted">Add Your Cafe</p>

                        <form id="my-form" name="cafe" method="post" action=""
                              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {{ cafe_form.csrf_token }}
                            {{ ckeditor.load() }}
                            {{ ckeditor.config(name='about') }}
                            {{ cafe_form.name.label }}
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                                {{ cafe_form.name(class="form-control") }}
                            </div>
                            <div id="data_container">
                                <div id="dynamic-fields">
                                    <table>
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Menu item</th>
                                            <th>Menu item Price in USD $</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody class="p-4">
                                        <tr class="p-2">
                                            <td><input  type="text"></td>
                                            <td><input  type="text"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="pt-2 pb-2">
                   <button id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary px-4">Submit</button>
                            <button id="add_rows" class="btn btn-outline-dark">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and this is my js for adding extra rows :

> ```
> $("#add_rows").click(function () {
>     // each click on the `+` button adds a row to the table
>     $("#data_container tbody").append(`<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>`);
> });
> $("#submit_rows").click(function () {
>     // `obj` for storing the inputs, and the `n` to make unrepeated keys
>     let obj = {}, n = 0;
>     // loop over the rows
>     $("#data_container tbody tr").each(function (ind, tr) {
>         // add an array to the object
>         obj[`r${n}`] = [];
>         // loop over the inputs of this row
>         $(this).find("input").each(function (ind, input) {
>             // add the value of the input to the array and make sure to remove any semicolon since
>             // we will use it to separate the inputs
>             const val = input.value.replace(/;/g, "");
>             obj[`r${n}`].push(val);
>         });
>         // no need for the array, just join it to a string of values separated by semicolons
>         obj[`r${n}`] = obj[`r${n}`].join(";");
>         // increase the value of `n`
>         n++;
>     });
>     // log the object to the console so you can see what we are sending
>     console.log(obj);
>     // send the data to the server, see the console for a logging message for success
>     $.post("", obj, (data, status) => console.log("Status: " + status));
> });
> ```

and this is the part that i try to send the data to back-end:

```
    const weburl = "/owner-new-cafe";
    document.getElementById('submit-btn').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    });

    function submitForm() {
        // Collect static form data
        const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('my-form'));

        // Collect dynamic form data
        const dynamicData = [];
        $('#dynamic-fields tbody tr').each(function () {
            const row = {};
            $(this).find('input').each(function (ind, input) {
                row[this.name] = this.value;
            });
            dynamicData.push(row);
        });

        // Add dynamic form data to FormData object
        formData.append('dynamicData', JSON.stringify(dynamicData));
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = formData;

        // Send form data to Flask app using AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: weburl,
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                // Handle response from Flask app
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                // Handle error
            }
        });

    }
```

please dont give me just answer iam try to learn i want to know what is my mistakle and what is the best way for doing this thank you so much

Comment: Hi, your input box doesn't have `name` attribute.

Comment: @Swati Hi thank uopu You right  that was one part of my problem i fix that but i fix the problem and i will share my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fix my problem one problem was when i put the button for add extra row for my dynamic table inside the flask form div so when i click each of submit button Ajax send two post request to my backend or when user just wan to add row again it send a post request and it act like a submit button some how
other problem was i dont assis the name for input for dynamic forom thank to [@Swati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10606400/swati)

so in this case i decide to have two div one for flask form and other one for my dynamic form like this :

## New Cafe

Add Your Cafe
            
                
                                {{ cafe_form.csrf_token }}
                                {{ ckeditor.load() }}
                                {{ ckeditor.config(name='about') }}
                                {{ cafe_form.name.label }}
                                
                                    
                                    {{ cafe_form.name(class="form-control") }}
                                       
                                
                                    {{ cafe_form.submit(id="submit_rows", class="btn btn-outline-primary px-4") }}
                                
                   
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                        
                                            Menu item
                                            Menu item Price in USD $
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                            
                                            
                                                
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                
                                +

and just use this JQuery cod to add extra row in dynamic form

> ```
> // dynamic row
> $("#add_rows").click(function() {
>   // each click on the `+` button adds a row to the table
>   $("#data_container tbody").append(`<tr><td><input class="input-group mb-3" 
>      name="item" type="text"></td><td><input
>  class="input-group mb-3" name="price" type="text"></td></tr>`);
> });
> $("#submit_rows").click(function() {
>   // `obj` for storing the inputs, and the `n` to make unrepeated keys
>   var obj = {}, n = 0;
>   // loop over the rows
>   $("#data_container tbody tr").each(function() {
>     // add an array to the object
>     obj[`r${n}`] = [];
>     // loop over the inputs of this row
>     $(this).find("input").each(function(ind, input) {
>       // add the value of the input to the array and make sure to remove any semicolon since
>       // we will use it to separate the inputs
>       var val = input.value.replace(/;/g, "");
>       obj[`r${n}`].push(val);
>     });
>     // no need for the array, just join it to a string of values separated by semicolons
>     obj[`r${n}`] = obj[`r${n}`].join(";");
>     // increase the value of `n`
>     n++;
>   });
>   // log the object to the console so you can see what we are sending
>   console.log(obj);
>   // send the data to the server, see the console for a logging message for success
>   $.post("", obj, (data, status) => console.log("Status: " + status));
> });
> ```

in my flask app route i get the values of both list with using `request.form.items()`and i think we can change it to dict by using to_dict in this case my cod is :

```
@private.route('/<city>/owner-new-cafe', methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
@confirmed_only
@owner_only
def owner_add_cafe(city):
    if request.method == "POST" and cafe_form.validate():
        print(request.form)
    for item in request.form.items():
        print(item)
    return "Job Done"
```